# Obtaining required keys for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python, forms

I have been using mechanize to fill in a form from a website but this now has changed and some of the required fields seem to be hidden and cannot be accessed using mechanize any longer - when printing all available forms.
I assume it has been modified to use more current methods (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) but I have not found a way to update my script to continue using this form programmatically.

From what I have read, I should be able to send a dict (key/value pair) to the submit button directly rather than filling the form in the first place - please correct me if I am wrong.
BUT I have not been able to find a way to obtain what keys are required...

I would massively appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or put me straight in case this is no longer possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, in all circumstances, extract all fields a server expects.

The post target, the code handling the POST, is a black box. You cannot look inside the code that the server runs. The best information you have about what it expects is what the original form tells your browser to post. That original form consists not only of the HTML, but also of the headers that were sent with it (cookies for example) and any JavaScript code that is run by the browser.

In many cases, parsing the HTML sent for the form is enough; that's what Mechanize (or a recent more modern framework like [robobrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) does, plus a little cookie handling and making sure typical headers such as the referrer are included. But if any JavaScript code *manipulated* the HTML or intercepts the form submission to add or remove data then Mechanize or other Python form parsers cannot replicate that step.

Your options then are to:

- Reverse engineer what the Javascript code does and replicate that in Python code. The development tools of your browser can help here; observe what is being posted on the network tab, for example, or use the debugger to step through the JavaScript code to see what it does.
- Use an actual browser, controlled from Python. Selenium could do this for you; it can drive a desktop browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) or it can be used to drive a headless browser implementation such as PhantomJS. This is heavier on the resources, but will actually run the JavaScript code and let you post a form just as your browser would, in each and every way.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This is already really helpful. Ill have to give it a try because i believe its is java that modifies the html. Unfortunately i dont think this will be feasible for what i want to do because i will have to fill the form 100000s times over which would be very slow when simulating a browser but it should give me a good starting point. Hopefully i can obtain the requited keys that way. I have not yet accepted the answer because i will probably have more in depth questions later on. Thanks

Comment: @T1M: this format is not really suitable for in-depth follow-up questions though. Hopefully I have given you something to think about though.

Comment: One follow up Q.: What would you say is the most robust way of doing this, most reliable quickest? Actually simulation exactly what the browser does (PhantomJS) or try to reverse engineer the java code?

Comment: @T1M: If at all possible, I'd reverse engineer the JS (Java **script**, Java is an entirely different language). It probably is something extremely simple to reproduce.