# Python - urllib2 how to know if our authorization is successful

Tags: python, authentication, request, authorization, urllib2

When you would normally login to a website we can use urllib2.Request as so.

```
import urllib2, base64
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.facebook.com/")
base64string = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % ("username", "password")).replace("\n", "")
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
requested = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

But how do we know if the authorization was successful? Because you could of just opened a URL of a wrong authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `urllib2.HTTPError` exception is raised when you are not authorised and a 401 status is returned:

```
>>> import urllib2, base64
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/foouser/barpw')
>>> base64string = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % ("username", "password")).replace("\n", "")
>>> req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
>>> urllib2.urlopen(req)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: UNAUTHORIZED
```

On successful authorisation you'll get a response object instead:

```
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/foouser/barpw')
>>> base64string = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % ("foouser", "barpw")).replace("\n", "")
>>> req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> response.getcode()
200
```

Comment: I don't get the urllib2.HTTPError exception with a right or wrong auth? I only get an exception error when I try connect to my router (default gateway) with a wrong password. Please help me.

Comment: Then the *specific* server is not responding with a 401 error but instead gives you a message in a 200 error page or perhaps they have redirected you. What are the response contents?

Comment: I done this on facebook, the code is 200 either right or wrong and the .geturl() for both right and wrong auths is https://www.facebook.com/. I also printed out the .info() and there is not much difference, just different "Set-Cookie" headers etc, but nothing about having the correct auth.

Comment: @user3818650: Facebook doesn't use basic auth, they use a cookie session.

Comment: So how would I log on with cookie sessions, knowing I have logged on?

Comment: @user3818650: this is getting too broad; generally you load the page and ensure that cookies are set, then post the information the login form tells your browser to send. See [Looking for Requests equivalent of Mechanize capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25893742) and [Obtaining required keys for application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25621883) for recent posts on handling forms.

Comment: is their anyway to do this with urllib/urllib2

Comment: @user3818650: sure, with care and patience. It depends on the exact login form you are handling; does it use a CSRF token? Does the server expect certain headers with the POST (only way to find out is to try), etc.

Comment: I was wondering since you know a lot about different login types, if you could find out yourself and show me the code, I would be really grateful.

Comment: @user3818650: no, sorry, I can't do that.